# Need help with economics headline that contains 還元

Tags: translation, meaning, syntax

Since I do not hold a degree in business, this headline has me stumped. *Please note all of these are my sad attempts at translation since the article is only in Japanese.*

**支払い時に還元、実質値引きへ**

> ***"Return at payment, to real discount"***
>
> ***"Reduction in the time of payment, to the substantial discount"***
>
> ***"Upon checkout, real discount offered at point of purchase"***
>
> ***"During payment, to real price reduction"***
>
> ***"When making a payment return, real price reduced towards"***
>
> ***"Price time reduced, becoming essence discount"***
>
> ***"Substantial discount from, time payment restoration"***
>
> ***"Payment reduction time, real discount to the towards"***
>
> ***"Reduce real discount, when paying"***
>
> ***"To reducing substantially discount, at the time of payment"***
>
> ***"Reduced to the time of payment, to substantial discount"***
>
> ***"At the time of payment reduced, to real discount"***

---

[Here](https://asia.nikkei.com/Economy/Japan-convenience-stores-to-offset-2-tax-hike-with-discounts) is some background info I found on a site that apparently translates articles from Japanese into English:

> *Cashless payments make up about a fifth of the total in Japan, putting it behind other countries making the switch away from cash.*
>
> *TOKYO -- Japan's convenience stores will offer 2% price discounts on the spot for cashless purchases starting October when the consumption tax rises to 10% from 8%, Nikkei has learned.*
>
> *It will be part of a government program aimed at cushioning the impact of the 2 percentage point tax hike, but instead of offering a 2% point reward to be used at a later date, the convenience stores will, in effect, cut prices at the point of purchase.*

Comment: Are all of these phrases below the Japanese attempted translations?  Also, is there a particular part of the phrase that's giving you trouble, or is it just generally difficult for you to translate?

Comment: You should link the article and the first sentence of it. It’s much clearer than this headline which is omitting critical words for brevity.

Comment: @ajsmart First thanks for even bothering to reply! Yes all these are my (pathetic) translation attempts. This was an article from the news.tbs site, and as we all know they delete all their articles basically a few days after its published, but I found another copy here https://www.hiramori-sr.com/c-kakei-005/

Comment: @SomaRise Please take notes on Chocolate’s edit btw, my eyes were bleeding on your original :)

Comment: @Darius あっ、most part of the edit was done by ＠kimiTanaka.

Comment: @to anyone who edited/correct my post, good job!

Answer (score 2):

[The article](https://www.hiramori-sr.com/c-kakei-005/) includes the headline in "expanded" form:

[...]コンビニ大手３社は、支払い時にその場で還元することで、実質的に値引きすることを検討していることがわかりました

Breaking it down:

> コンビニ大手３社は
>
> The three big convenience store companies/chains
>
> 支払い時に
>
> At the time of payment
>
> その場で還元することで
>
> by [doing the] refund at the same place/time
>
> 実質的に値引きすることを
>
> [the practice of] offering a real discount
>
> 検討していることがわかりました
>
> it was found [that they are] considering [it]

Combining it all:

[we] discovered that the three big chains are considering offering real discounts via refund/pay back on the spot at the time of payment.

実質的 is defined as "substantial; real (as opposed to nominal)​" and is used here probably to indicate that the discount will effectively bring the price paid back to the pre-hike level and is not just a bonus in points to be spent later.

Going back to the headline:

> 支払い時に還元、実質値引きへ

Could possibly be translated as:

"Pay-time refunds to result in real discounts"

However it doesn't quite capture the subtext of the article... The English article you linked ("to offset 2% tax hike with discounts") carries it over it much better, which is probably why they did not use a literal translation.

P.S. maybe something like:

"Pay-time refund brings back the original price"

it's not quite as literal but feels closer as a summary of the article

Comment: Thanks for the help! I would like to apologize if my question was of any burden to @Igor or anyone else. But more importantly, I am ever so grateful for this very detailed help, since my weakness is economic and business when I try to read japanese, this is a step in the right direction. I also posted this question on reddit - the response I got over there is similar to yours in some ways. Hopefully I'll improve my "economics" portion of my studies so as to not have to rely solely on others. https://www.reddit.com/r/translator/comments/d9mjuc/japaneseenglish_need_help_with_economics_headline/